# Azure Devops pipelines set bash shell options for entire pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to set default shell options for the entire pipelines file?

In github actions you could do it at the workflow level using the 'defaults > shell' value e.g. `bash --noprofile --norc -eo pipefail {0}`

and this would affect all shell steps in the entire workflow. As far as I can tell, there is no equivalent option in azure devops and I would be forced to copy/paste for each 'bash' task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not supported to set default shell options in Azure DevOps. Every bash task represents a new session in one Azure Pipeline workflow.

You could create a new Azure DevOps feature request via : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can add the [SHELLOPTS variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-SHELLOPTS) for the entire pipeline, which would at least get you the `-eo pipefail` part:

```
variables:
  SHELLOPTS: errexit:pipefail
```

Comment: this is great and appears like it will accomplish what I was looking for! thanks for the suggestion!